# pulp python - Variable taking heavy time to load : gives Out of Memory error

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am working on an optimization model and using the below decision variable

```
Experts = range(10000)
Skills = range(59)
```

```
zVals = [(i,u,j,v,p) for p in projects for i in Experts for u in Skills for j in Experts for v in Skills if i>j if u!=v ]
z = pu.LpVariable.dicts("z",zVals,0,1,pu.LpBinary)
```

I guess Memory Error when I try and load data in zVals. Can anyone help?New to ILP,python

Comment: Some basic arithmetic will tell you just how many elements zVals would have if your computer had enough memory to hold it all. If you don’t need all the elements to be in memory at once you might want to use an iterator instead.

Comment: That loop goes for `10 000^2 * 59^2 = 348100000000` iterations. Even if you didn't store anything (giving the memory error here), that loop would probably __never__ finish. So you probably need to rethink your approach, even if using an iterator would solve the memory issue.

Comment: @barny@Bendik- Thank you so much, I believe I will have to work on how to reduce the no. of vars here